# mapbox customlayer autoclearcolor

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl-js

I have a question about mapbox autoclearcolor setup when it uses three.js custom layer.

I managed to make a cube within a mapspace using the customlayer setup in mapbox and
I wanted to make the map layer visible at the beginning and turned it visible in a certain moment.By doing things as below.

**In onAdd method,**

```
    this.map = map;
    this.canvas = map.getCanvas()

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: map.getCanvas(),
        context: gl,
        antialias: true
    });

    this.renderer.autoClear = false;
```

**In render Method,**

```
    if(frameCount>10 && frameCount<11){
        this.renderer.autoClear = true;

    }
```

I by accident made it happened but I don't know why it happened.

```
    frameCount += 0.1

    if(frameCount>10 && frameCount<11){
        this.renderer.autoClear = true;

    }
```

In three.js document it says

*.autoClear : Boolean
Defines whether the renderer should automatically clear its output before rendering a frame.*

I don't get how it works.
To me it sounds like,
if I set autoClear true, it should clear things in the scene and if it's true,
I shouldn't see anything but by setting this, only the map tile is gone and my mesh and map labels are still alive like the screen shot below.

**after autoclear is set true**
[image: after autoclear is set true]

**Before autoclear becomes true, currently it's false which is default value**
[image: Before autoclear becomes true, currently it's false which is default value]

Comment: Why don’t you just change the style to an empty one?

Comment: @jscastro Since I want to make a transition from empty one. Changing map tiles doesn't allow me to have the transition.